# Using devexpress HtmlEditor control has DXR.axd throwing 404

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I am using a dev express control: ASPxHtmlEditor version 10.1.  I am trying to create a simple that only has this control.  Unfortunately the control does not render with any of its styles or images loaded.  This happens over 20 times.  The control does not have any of its styles and all of its images do not load on the control.

I am getting 404 exceptions similar to: "Failed to load source http://localhost:11238/DXR.axd?r=5_0"

Answer (score 2):

The cause of this issue is that the web.config file did not contain our http handler registration.  So, such requests were not properly handled and scripts and images did not come to the client.  Once you open the page in the designer, the http handler was registered and the problem disappeared :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to restart my machine and open the page the control was on in design mode to have it create all the controls it needs to render properly.